# Android broadcast UDP works but Unicast doesn't

Tags: android, sockets

I am trying to develop a sample application that listens for udp broadcast packets over the network and once it receives the the broadcast it replies back the client with another packet.After getting the rep;y from the server the client is sending a unicast message to the server which is not being received.It is working fine till receiving broadcast  and replying back however receiving the unicast message is not working.I am posting the code.Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyDatagramReceiver extends Thread {
    private boolean bKeepRunning = true;
    private String lastMessage = null;
    private Handler mHandler = null;
    private DatagramSocket datagramsocket = null;
    DatagramPacket packet = null;
    private static InetAddress Serverip = null;
    private static int port = 8090;

    public MyDatagramReceiver(Handler handler) {

        this.mHandler = handler;
        Log.v("MyDatagramReceiver", "Handler Initialised");

    }

    public void run() {
        String message = null;
        InetAddress ip = null;

        byte[] lmessage = new byte[10];

        try {
            Serverip = getDeviceIP();
            Log.v("MyDatagramReceiver", "DeviceIp:" + Serverip);
            datagramsocket = new DatagramSocket(port, Serverip);
            datagramsocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
            datagramsocket.setBroadcast(true);

            Log.v("MyDatagramReceiver", "Socket CREATED");

            while (bKeepRunning) {

                packet = new DatagramPacket(lmessage, lmessage.length);
                Log.v("MyDatagramReceiver", "RECEIVING PACKET CREATED");

                datagramsocket.receive(packet);
                Log.v("MyDatagramReceiver", "PACKET RECEIVED");

                message = new String(lmessage);
                Log.v("MyDatagramReceiver", "Received packet contains:"
                        + message);

                ip = packet.getAddress();
                Log.v("MyDatagramReceiver", "IP" + ip);
                lastMessage = message;
                Log.v("MyDatagramReceiver", "lastmessage contains:"
                        + lastMessage);
                String var = message;
                Message completeMessage = mHandler.obtainMessage();
                completeMessage.obj = var;
                Log.v("MyDatagramReceiver", "completeMessage" + completeMessage);
                completeMessage.sendToTarget();
                byte[] m = "Hello_client".getBytes();
                InetAddress aHost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

                DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(m, m.length, ip,
                        port);
                datagramsocket.send(request);
                Log.v("MyDatagramReceiver", "Packet sent");
            }
            if (datagramsocket != null) {
                datagramsocket.close();
            }

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void kill() {
        bKeepRunning = false;
    }

    public String getLastMessage() {
        return lastMessage;
    }

    public static InetAddress getDeviceIP() {
        if (Serverip != null) {
        } else {
            try {
                for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface
                        .getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                    NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                    for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf
                            .getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                        InetAddress intAdress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                        if (!intAdress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                            if (intAdress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                                Serverip = intAdress;
                                Log.d("ServerIpHelper", "Client Ip Address: "
                                        + Serverip.getHostAddress().toString());
                                return Serverip;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return Serverip;
    }

}
```

Comment: I only see a single datagramsocket.send, where do you send your unicast message ?

Comment: I am sending this packet to the client as the reply